# 8bpp scaling with Direct2d

Tags: direct2d

I want to scale a 1920x1080 image to 1280x720. The source and destination buffers are both in main memory.  Each pixel is 8 bits.  The images are the Y component of a video frame.

For best performance, I want to avoid buffer copy.  IWICBitmapScaler can do the scaling but is very slow.  I'm trying Direct2D, but I can't get DrawBitmap to work for an A8 Render Target.  I get hr = 0x88982f80 : The bitmap pixel format is unsupported.  How can I use DrawBitmap with an A8 render target?

Comment: What's A8 render target? and where is your code?

Comment: @zdd An A8 render target uses only 8 bits per pixel, wich are interpreted as transparency: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663563(v=vs.85).aspx